# Firebase - problems with retrieving database values using once()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been having this problem for a whole day now, I'm trying to retrieve a value from my realtime database using once() but it will only give me back either an undefined value or a promise that doesn't resolve or reject. I first wrote my own snippet of code based on the example given in the documentation (which - despite my best efforts - I couldn't understand very well) however it constantly returned "undefined" no matter what I tried, here's the code that I wrote:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + window.userid + '/MGScore').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    window.highscore = snapshot.val();
    // ...
});
console.log(highscore);
```

Eventually I decided to just copy and paste the example used in the documentation and just change the names, but it too ran into problems in the form of promises being returned which never resolved themselves or got rejected:

```
function checkHighscore() {
    var userId = window.userid;
    return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        var highscore = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().MGScore) || 'Anonymous';
        // ...
    });
}
```

I'm not sure how to deal with this and I was hoping somebody can help rectify this issue.

Comment: If the promise never resolves, it sounds like Firebase doesn't have an internet connection.  What does the browser console log say?

Comment: The second source code returns a promise.  What do you do with the return value?

Comment: `console.log(snapshot.val();` and view what you get back in your browser (cntr +shft + i). If `undefined` make sure your ref is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be handling you promises incorrectly.

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + window.userid + '/MGScore').once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    window.highscore = snapshot.val();
    // ...
});
console.log(highscore);
```

I'm assuming `highscore` should be `window.highscore` as in this example it would be undefined?

You're mixing async/sync workflows.

```
// Execute 1st
firebase.database().ref('users/' + window.userid + '/MGScore').once('value')
  .then(function (snapshot) {
      // Execute 3rd
      window.highscore = snapshot.val();
  });

// Execute 2nd
console.log(highscore);
```

The console log would execute before the thenable function - because it's async and waiting for firebase to return a response.

You might need to refactor your code to something like the below;

```
baseFunction() {
  // Execute 1st
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + window.userid + '/MGScore').once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
        // Execute 2nd
        window.highscore = snapshot.val();

        // Highscore is set - Call next function
        highscoreSet();
    });
}

highscoreSet() {
  // Execute 3rd
  console.log(highscore);
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, this method worked for me and the console is now displaying the value as originally intended..